# FullTextSqlQuery - cant add ContentType to Query

Tags: search, fulltextsqlquery

I'm using FullTextSqlQuery to perform search on a specific list. Query returns results properly, but when I try to add ContentType column to select clause

```
SELECT Title,ContentType,Path FROM SCOPE() WHERE FREETEXT('pojazd')  AND (CONTAINS(Path,'"/BW/Lists/Pytania Bazy Wiedzy"'))
```

I'm getting error:

```
Unhandled Exception: The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason.
```

After inspecting ULS, I found the following:

```
SearchServiceApplicationProxy::Execute--Error occured: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationFault]: The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason. (Fault Detail is equal to Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationFault).
```

When I remove ContentType column, query performs properly. I'll also note, that I'm running my code from console application.

Comment: May be this link (http://blogs.technet.com/b/saantil/archive/2011/05/01/getting-quot-the-search-request-was-unable-to-connect-to-the-search-service-quot.aspx) will help

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use all SharePoint `Managed Properties` in your `FullTextSqlQuery`. `Managed Properties` have a property called `Retrievable` which defines if you can use the property or not. The `ContentType` property cannot be used.

To solve this problem you can create your own `Managed Property` and mapp it to the `ContentType` property.

For more information:

[Refining on Content Type in SharePoint 2010](http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2011/01/refining-on-content-type-in-sharepoint-2010/)
[Create a content type search refinement panel in SharePoint 2010](http://www.glynblogs.com/2011/01/create-a-content-type-search-refinement-panel-in-sharepoint-2010.html)
[Crawled properties reference (Search Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh134176%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box content type property doesn't work in queries. So workaround to this problem is to create new managed property and map this new managed property with crawled properties with which ContentType managed property is mapped (see below).

[image]

See [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/4932/issue-with-content-type-managed-property-in-search-for-share.aspx) for more details