# SharePoint 2010 - get list item from search result

Tags: list, search, splistitem, fulltextsqlquery

I'm using `FullTextSqlQuery` to search items on specific list. Query returns results properly. Now I'd like to get `SPListItem` from search results. As I searched Internet, I found couple of examples, but they all are based on document libraries - getting file and associated with that file `SPListItem`.

My results contain path to item in such format:

```
https://<site>/<web>/Lists/<list>/DispForm.aspx?ID=5
```

I tried to use `SPWeb`'s method `GetListItem(path)` with server relative url from above path, but returned item is `null`

So is there any way to get `SPListItem` from list based on item path returned from search results?

Comment: what you're actually trying to do

Comment: I want to obtain SPListItem from given search result. Search query is written so it returns results from only one list, and I'd like to get those items.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the `SPListItem` by the ID provided in the URL.

For example if you have this URL: `https://<site>/<web>/Lists/<list>/DispForm.aspx?ID=5` the ID of the item is 5. So you can use the `SPList.GetItemById()` method and pass the item ID as argument.

**EDIT:**

There is another way to get the `SPListItem` by using the `SPWeb.GetFile()` with the `owsItemUrl` value as argument. After you get the `SPFile` object you can use the `SPFile.Item` property to get the `SPListItem`.

*Example:*

If the `FullTextSqlQuery` is called query:

```
ResultTableCollection result = query.Execute();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
if (result.Count > 0)
{
    using (ResultTable relevantResults = result[ResultType.RelevantResults])
    {
        dt.Load(relevantResults, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            if (row["ContentType"].ToString() == "Item")
            {
                using (SPSite lookupSite = new SPSite(row["owsItemUrl"].ToString()))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = lookupSite.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        SPFile file = web.GetFile(row["owsItemUrl"].ToString());
                        SPListItem spListItem = file.Item;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This the think I'd like to avoid, but in the end it might be only solution.

Comment: @jjczopek Plese try my new edits, maybe that will help.

Comment: I can't add owsItemUrl to my query, because it throws error. Same thing when I add ContentType. :/

Comment: You can use my first suggestion or try my answer to your other question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54826/fulltextsqlquery-cant-add-contenttype-to-query